# How to get selected option from "select" tag on mobile browser?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the selected value from the following drop down list

```
<select id = "sel123">
  <option selected value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Here is what I try

```
 alert($("#sel123 option:selected").text());
```

**I works fine on desktop browser.**

But when I test the same thing on mobile device, the `jquery`ALWAYS pulls the "Volvo" option no matter what I choose . **What i mean is when I select "Saab", or "Audi" the drop down shows "Saab", or "Audi" . . . but the `jquery` alert still shows "Volvo"**

Why is it happening? How to get the "selected" value on a mobile browser? (I have been testing it on Airwatch browser IPhone and Chrom Android)

EDIT: I suspect this  might be because I have `selected` attr preset within the "Volvo" option and the mobile browser is not identifying the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alert if a change happens. Try like so:

```js
$("#sel123").change(function() {
  alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "sel123">
  <option selected value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

read more about [jQuery change() here](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I cant thank you enough. i didnt sleep last night. i dont know my version didnt work. but your magic works :)

Comment: @john you're welcome. glad it helped! There's no magic. The function just waits until the select changes. When it changes then it moves on with whatever is written inside the function. In this case it alerts something.

Comment: Sorry, but `change()` does not work if you reuse already selected value!

Comment: @qraqatit, yes that is correct and how it should be. Because, if you select the same value which is selected, there is no change.

Comment: @caramba I am not questioning correctness of the change() event, I am saying that you won't get response if you reselect already selected option, thus this will not works in such cases (user may have his reasons why he wants to know/get response from select action also for reselecting).

Answer (score 0):

Lets try removing the `selected` attribute as soon as any change occurs

```
$("#sel123").change(function() {
  $(this).find("option[selected]").removeAttr('selected');
});
```

Comment: As I said above: `change()` does not work if you reuse already selected value!